# How to connect asp net core MVC to another asp net core SignalR server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

i have a Aspnet core web application ,
want to connect to asp net core signalR server that is in the another server
with different url , in controller .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ASP.NET Core SignalR .NET Client`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client).

This library lets you communicate with `SignalR` hubs from `.NET` apps.